# File from multithreaded download different from single threaded

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have been experimenting with multithreading lately, and I coded an application that downloads a file with HTTPUrlConnection's Range request property. I first get the length of the file from the header, and then I split it up into X number of equal parts, and if there is a remainder, I assign one more thread to take up the slack. Then each of the parts go into an object inside of a queue. Then multiple threads access each task in the queue and execute it, downloading each part concurrently into separate files.

The way that I join the files is the problem. No matter whether I use Linux `cat` or Windows' `copy /B` or `type`, it always comes out that the resulting file comes out invalid in some way.

With AVI files, the index is broken, but when rebuilt, the AVI plays correctly. With .rar files winrar displays "unexpected end of archive", although the files extract normally. What could be causing this. I made sure that no bytes overlapped when I split it up amongst threads.

Comment: Can you add some more information on your question? I thinks its very unclear

Comment: I'd download the (original) full file and do a hex dump of the original and of the reassembled one in two parallel windows.  That way you can see what content is the same and what content is different.  All of the utilities you mention are intended for text content rather than binary, so it wouldn't surprise me if they didn't behave correctly when you use them with these binary files.  I'd instead use `FileInputStream`s to re-read your segments one at a time after they're all downloaded and write them into a single `FileOutputStream` in the right order.

Comment: What I am finding in the hex editor is that there is at least one character offset for each part that I make. The changes are rippling, and I have to isolate where the change is happening.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, Ill post it on Gist

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/350b1a911cae5c3725ca

The library from the "queue" package is of my own making, but that is just to handle the threads.

Comment: Is the extra character (I'm assuming "offset" means something was inserted, rather than deleted) the same in all cases?  (Is it a \r or a \n, for example?)  It definitely could be an artifact of the use of `cat`/`copy`/`type`...

Comment: In `FileSplitter`, you've got a bug in `list.add(new DownloadPart(pos+1, byteSize, savePath, url, String.valueOf(ch)));`; it should be `lastPieceLeftoverPos`, not `byteSize`.  Shouldn't matter, since you're going to get the last set of bytes either way, but it makes the code clearer.

Comment: The character I saw was OE (HEX), which is a "." in ASCII. Is that it? Looking at the size of all the parts combined, it is 9 bytes more than the original. So it is not the fault of the command line copy tools. It is somewhere in my code then. I flushed each connection and writer after I had downloaded all the parts, so I don't understand where the fault might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the Range parameter to the request incorrectly.  The end index is for the last character to be read, **inclusive**, while your algorithm passes the index for the first character that you don't want transferred.  Subtract 1 from the argument you pass as the `end` argument to `DownloadPart`, and you should be fine:

```
list.add(new DownloadPart(pos, pos + pieceLen - 1, savePath, url, String.valueOf(ch)));
```

You've also got some unnecessary duplication of code that you should probably clean up; your first full block doesn't need to be treated any differently than any other full block, which would simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was stuck in the mentality of the leftovers being different so I made the first part unnecessarily different.

But it is still one byte short. Would that mean that FileSplitter:35 would be: 
'list.add(new DownloadPart(pos, byteSize, savePath, url, String.valueOf(ch)));'

Comment: I'd handle the "leftovers" differently; you should only do N downloads, not N+1 for the leftovers, because it's inefficient to do a HTTP connection for just a couple bytes.  So compute `pieceLen` by rounding up not down, and then have the last piece be a little shorter than the others.

Comment: You can also have a variable within the loop for how many bytes to get for that loop iteration; it'll be pieceLen every time but the last, and `byteSize % pieces` the last time.  Then you can use that in the call to construct a DownloadPart and use it, so you're not duplicating that code.  (And it's easier to see what's different between the different iterations.)  In general, you want to find ways to avoid rewriting code that's almost the same; figure out what's different between the two, pull that out into a method or a variable or a class, and then write the complicated code using it.